# How to indent XML properly using XMLSerializer?

Tags: java, android, xml-serialization, indentation

I'm having a hard time trying to indent XML files using `XMLSerializer`.

I've tried

```
serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output",
                      true);
```

I've tried to append `\n` into `FileWriter` but the output is the `\n`'s and `\t`'s at the beginning of the file and not in the right place. I've tried `setPropery` with the proper URI etc.

Part of the code:

```
XmlPullParserFactory parserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
parserFactory .setNamespaceAware(true);
XmlSerializer serializer = parserFactory .newSerializer();
File xmlFile = new File(PATH + ".xml");         
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(xmlFile);            
serializer.setOutput(writer);
//serializer.setProperty(INDENT_URL, INDENT);
serializer.startDocument("UTF-8", null);
//serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output",
                        true);
serializer.startTag(null, "bla");
writer.append('\n');
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using these two properties "in combination" on Serializer?

```
// indentation as 3 spaces
serializer.setProperty(
   "http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/properties.html#serializer-indentation", "   ");
// also set the line separator
serializer.setProperty(
   "http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/properties.html#serializer-line-separator", "\n");
```

Comment: Yes. I did and it gave me this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported Property:
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlSerializer.setProperty(KXmlSerializer.java:260)....

Comment: @Eduardo Berton : This is not the correct answer, it does not work

Comment: I'm want to delete this since this is not working for a lot of people. Can the author of the question un-accept the answer?

Answer (score 39):

`serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);` worked now.

I dont know if i was putting it before `serializer.startDocument(encoding, standalone)` or there was a error with stuff not related to the .xml creation!

Thanks guys!

Comment: how to indent comments then?

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution in Java, andriod does support transformer so this should work.

```
// import additional packages
import java.io.*;

// import DOM related classes
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

// write the output file
try {
  // create a transformer
  TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
  Transformer        transformer  = transFactory.newTransformer();

  // set some options on the transformer
  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "utf-8");
  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
  transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");

  // get a transformer and supporting classes
  StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
  StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
  DOMSource    source = new DOMSource(xmlDoc);

  // transform the xml document into a string
  transformer.transform(source, result);

  // open the output file
  FileWriter outputWriter = new FileWriter(outputFile);
  outputWriter.write(writer.toString());
  outputWriter.close();

} catch(javax.xml.transform.TransformerException e) {
  // do something with this error
}catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
  // do something with this error
}
```

Comment: :) I just have good google foo today. XML serialiser is to serialise data to XML, and file writer does writing to a file. So the responsibility to format to something human readable lies in another class if it already exists :)

Comment: I tried this, but I keep getting non-indented files :( No errors though.

Comment: If I can add something here, be sure to ```replaceAll("[\\s]+", "")``` in case of strings. In my case the xml string already had ```\n``` and the indenting was not happening.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to make a note that `Transformer.setOutputProperties(Properties)` doesn't seems to work for me (1.6.0_26_b03), but `Transformer.setOutputProperty(String,String)` does perfectly.
If you have a Properties object, you might have to iterate and individually set the output property for it to work.