# Creating XML file with identation

Tags: android, xml, xmlserializer

How can I create a XML file that has identation or, at least, line breaks between each tag?

I'm using class XMLSerializer (available in Android) to handle the XML creation.

```
XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

serializer.setOutput(writer);
String xmlFileContents = writer.toString();
```

Then I use the contents of xmlFileContents to create a file, using a BufferedWriter. The file is written, but the XML is not idented, and would like it to be.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XMLSerializer & Indentation \[SOLVED\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638283/xmlserializer-indentation-solved)

Comment: That's not how you create an XmlSerializer in Android.  org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer is an interface.

Or are you using the apache xerce's XMLSerializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

already solved: [How to indent XML properly using XMLSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638283/xmlserializer-indentation-solved)

Comment: Yeah I found it meanwhile. Thanks. Will try that solution.